# How to store month and year in the mm/yyyy format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table that stores month and year of a bill in the "mm/yyyy" format. Is there a data type that I can use directly or I will have to think of some other way?

Comment: You can use the `date` data type; Dates are not "stored" in any particular format, that's the job of your presenation layer.

Comment: Use an actual date field, and you can always supplement that with another field for the month (integer) and a third field for the year (integer). Or, you can create a Date table and reference the PK to the date table. Formatting is for the presentation layer (screen, reports, etc.) and not for the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use date data type and then when you retrieve the data from the table, you can format it as `mm/yyyy` by using `DATE_FORMAT` in your `select` statement as follows:

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(`yourdatecolumname`, "%m-%Y") FROM `yourtablename` WHERE....
```

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the data is not important to you, you can use columns for month and day, or you can just keep the date and ask it in the format DATE_FORMAT(your_date,'%Y%d'). If you care about the footprint of the data, define an integer and make sense of its bits. For example 4 bits for month and 8 bits for year. for 09/2021;
9:1001
21:0001 0101
decimal 2325.
month information CEIL(2325/256)
and the year information is 2325%256.
But as I mentioned at the beginning, if the size of the data is not important, you don't have to deal with them.